# Why are my link pages not being indexed?

Tags: seo, google, backlinks

I tried something but it didn't work. Iwill try to explain what I tried to do and probably someone could suggest what can be done.

I have a few websites, about 75, all in the same niche (travel).

I created a link directory sort of pages and uploaded all the pages (about 17 pages with about 10 links in each page) and uploaded the same pages to about 30 domains to see what kind of results I get.

I also created a separate sitemap for the links and uploaded in each of the domains.

I have waited close to two months now.

All the other pages of my website, let's say above 98% of the other pages, are indexed but for my link pages.

Any ideas as to why the pages are not being indexed?

I am thinking of adding bit more of data in each of the pages so that it doesn't look like just a link page. Would that work?

All your suggestions and inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google is wise to inter-linking sites owned by one person/business (or even beyond that), and it will hurt you (if it hasn't already).

Also, what extension are the domains you own? If they're .info they may still be affected by Google's penalty due to the large amount of spam .info domains that popped up a while back due to how cheap they are. If I remember correctly, .info domains younger than 6 months old may not appear in SERPS.

Comment: 90% of them are .com websites.. most of these website figure in the 1st or the second page of google for their relevant keywords..my issue is that the link pages are just not indexed!! god knows why..

Answer (score 0):

I am webmaster with around 20 websites. I am experiencing the same problem.

Google seams to know which pages are for advertising/linking purposes and therefore doesn't index them.

My guess is that Google is based on several factors in order to achieve that.

1. Checks page meta tags for "link, advertise" etc words.
2. Counts the outgoing external links on the page
3. Combines words like "exchange, link, advertise" with the number of outgoing links

I didn't have the luck to misslead it so far. But i have an idea about how to do it.

1.Place more internal links than external
2.Don't mention what this page is about (ofcourse not in meta also)
3.Use an irrelavent body main text to misslead Google

My base is [Web Development](http://www.webdeco.gr) <- here, in case someone wants to talk more about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

What are you hoping to achieve by having them indexed?   If somebody searches for one of the sites that is linked on the page, wouldn't you expect them to be happier going directly to the site, rather than landing on a page of links?

Google is very choosy these days about how many pages it indexes.  It doesn't index pages with very little content.   If it does index a page and then finds that users all back out of it and look at other search results, it may choose not to index it in the future.

Just because a page isn't indexed, doesn't mean that it isn't fulfilling its purpose.  It sounds like you want these pages to be a sitemap to let Googlebot know about all your websites and crawl them all.   These pages will be doing that whether or not they get indexed.